# What is the meaning of the phrase _____ killed my dog?

Tags: phrases

Yesterday, I was listening to a podcast and the host said something like _______ killed my dog. What is the meaning of that phrase?

Comment: Please link to the podcast.  I'm not aware of a particular idiom in use here but more context could help.  When you quote from a source that is online, please **link to the source**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That, on its own, is not a phrase. So either it was literal (I hope not!), or the context may have meant it metaphorically. For instance:

- "____ was so cruel that they may as well have killed my dog."
- "What ____ did was was as cruel as killing my dog."
- "I looked so sad, as though ____ killed my dog."

I don't know of, nor can I find online, any other such idiomatic expression in English.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).